# Using Regular Expression for assigning multiple variables

Tags: c#, regex

I have a xml duration in the format of "0H0M0.25S", where H, M, S stands for hour, month, second.
Now I wish to parse this string and assign it to integer hour, minute, and double second.
 i.e.

```
string s="0H0M0.25S";//input
int hour, minute;double second;//variable to assign
```

is there a way to achieve it using regular expression, which can assign all this variable in one go?

Comment: Perhaps you mean `hour, minute, second` instead of `hour, month, second` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = Regex.Match(s, @"(\d*)H(\d*)M(\d*.\d*)");
hour = int.Parse(result.Groups[1].Value);
minute = int.Parse(result.Groups[2].Value);
second = double.Parse(result.Groups[3].Value);
```

You might need to compensate for culture while parsing double.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can ditch Regex altogether and work with  `DateTime`:

```
    string datePattern = @"H\Hm\Ms.ff\S";
    var date = new DateTime();

    if (DateTime.TryParseExact("0H0M0.25S", datePattern, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
    {
        // Everything you need is in 'date' in just one go :)
        int hour = date.Hour;
        int minute = date.Minute;
        double second = (double)date.Second + ((double)date.Millisecond / 1000);
    }
    else 
    {
        // Catch invalid datetime string here
    }
```